# Array data only renders to HTML table every second event, otherwise undefined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, dom

```
// Relevant code: 

const searchBtn = document.getElementById("search-btn");
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const leftTable = document.querySelector("#left-table");
let url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=?";
let tagsUrl;
let dataArr;
let names = [];
let language = [];
let latestTag = [];
let tableDataArr = [names, language, latestTag];

// Fetch first 2 items for repos containing user query
function search(newURL) {
  fetch(newURL, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "xxxx" 
    }
  })
    .then(resp => {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      dataArr = data.items.slice(0, 2);
      return extractData();
    });
  input.value = ""; 
}

// Extract necessary values from returned object (language, name, latest tag) and push to corresponding arrays
function extractData() {
  dataArr.forEach(i => {
    names.push(i.full_name);
    language.push(i.language);
    fetch(i.tags_url)
      .then(resp => {
        return resp.json();
      })
      .then(resp => {
        if (resp[0]) {
         latestTag.push(resp[0].name);
        } else {
         latestTag.push(" ");
        }
        return console.log(tableDataArr);
      });
    //  getLatestTag(i.tags_url);
  });
  renderData();
}

// Render array data to HTML table
function renderData() {
  tableDataArr[0].forEach((i, j) => {
    let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    newRow.className = "row";
    newRow.innerHTML = `<td class='cell'>${i}</td>
    <td class='cell'>${tableDataArr[1][j]}</td>
    <td class='cell'>${tableDataArr[2][j]}</td>
    <td class='cell'><button class='add-btn'>Add</button></td>`;
    leftTable.appendChild(newRow);
  });
}

// User input event listeners
searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  search(url + input.value);
});

input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    search(url + input.value);
  }
});
```

I need the contents from each array inside tableDataArr to render to a HTML table after an event listener fires. The contents from tableDataArr[0] and tableDataArr[1] are rendering every time with no issue.

But, the contents from tableDataArr[2] render undefined with the first call, then render properly the next call, then undefined and so on with this alternating pattern between undefined and the data. What is going on here?

Comment: This probably isn't helping: `return console.log(tableDataArr)`

Comment: I've console.logged pretty much everything. The tableDataArr looks like a perfectly normal array with 3 items, each of which look perfectly normal themselves. No idea what's going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch and the chained thens will return a Promise object. you can push all of this into an array and use Promise.all() to check if all your fetches and thens are complete before calling renderData()

This sample code will guide you...

```js
// Extract necessary values from returned object (language, name, latest tag) and push to corresponding arrays
function extractData() {
  let psArr = [];
  dataArr.forEach(i => {
    names.push(i.full_name);
    language.push(i.language);
    let ps = fetch(i.tags_url)
      .then(resp => {
        return resp.json();
      })
      .then(resp => {
        if (resp[0]) {
         latestTag.push(resp[0].name);
        } else {
         latestTag.push(" ");
        }
        return resp;
      });
    psArr.push(ps);
    //  getLatestTag(i.tags_url);
  });
  Promise.all(psArr).then(()=>{
    renderData();
    });
}
```

It is important to note the when chaining `then`s to a promise, the promise that is assigned to the variable is the promise of the last chained `then`.

Also since this is all asynchronous the order can change depending on completion of the fetches, and this could result in unpredictable behavior.

Comment: shouldnt it be Promise.all(psArr)?

Comment: Thank you so much! Promise.all fixed everything :)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `renderData` before the `fetch` completes so it hasn't finished fetching yet. Try moving it to inside the `then` to see what I mean.

`fetch` is asynchronous - it has to wait on a network response - and the code you have written inside the `then` waits for it to complete, but the `renderData` is being called right away, before that item has been pushed onto the array.

It seems like even with this change your code could be error prone if you are doing multiple fetches and pushing onto an array this way - the `tags` could be pushed out of order and not match up with the `names` as you might expect.